# Update password error

Tags: php, pdo

I have problem updating my password. It keep showing database error but everything is fine.

My PHP coding, anything wrong here?

```
<?php
require ("config1.php");
 if(!empty($_POST)){
$lecID=$_GET['lecID'];
$query = "UPDATE lect SET lecass= :lecass WHERE leID = $leID ";

$query_params=array(':lecass'=> $_POST['leass']);

try{
    $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
    $result=$stmt->execute($query_params);

}catch(PDOException $ex){
    $response["success"]=0;
    $response["message"]="Database Error1. Please try again";
    die(json_encode($response));
    }
}?>
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Why only bind one of two query parameters?

Comment: Also, why not actually get some information about the error? `$response['message'] = $ex->getMessage();`

Comment: My guess is you'll find that `$_GET['lecID']` is unset for your POST request. You should definitely be binding both parameters, ie `UPDATE lecturer SET lecPass = ? WHERE lecID = ?` and `$stmt->execute([$_POST['lecPass'], $_GET['lecID']])`. Also, **never store plain-text passwords in your database** >:(

Comment: What? No! That's exactly what you have already

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your query should be

`"UPDATE lecturer SET lecPass=".$query_params[:lec_Pass]." WHERE lecID = $lecID ";`

**UPDATE**

1.

```
$query = "UPDATE lecturer SET lecPass= :lec_Pass WHERE lecID = :lec_id ";

$query_params=array(':lec_Pass' => $_POST['lecPass'],':lec_id' => $_GET['lecID'] );
```

2.

```
$query = "UPDATE lecturer SET lecPass= ? WHERE lecID = ? ";    
try{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $lecpass, $lecID);
    $lecpass = $_POST['lecPass'];
    $lecID = $_GET['lecID']; // I think you should use either post or get...
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

and also, tell me in the comment why you are using get and post both?

Comment: system.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: yes i didn't notice the code for binding parameters.. my bad

Comment: Any other solution please ?

Comment: did you try `$ex->getMessage()` as mentioned by @phil ?

Comment: try without using prepared statements first.

Comment: I'm updating my answer, hope it helps